# Make ODBC Connection in PHP Script from Hosted Platform

Tags: php, odbc, openedge

We have a Progress OpenEdge 10 database on our local network holding... among other things... our warehouse inventory.   I want to provide our staff with a simple way, on our website, to view/search this inventory.  Our website is a WordPress site hosted on WPEngine.  My plan is to do this with either a custom plugin, or just a simple php script.  Either way... I need to make a connection to this local database in my php script.

Obviously... if the web server was ours ... I would simply install the Progress ODBC drivers and create a System DSN.  But since WPEngine is hosting and they have indicated that they cannot provide the DSN, I'm not entirely sure what options I have to make this connection.

Worst case scenario is to build all of this on a local web server with the ODBC drivers and display it on our web site via iFrame, but we really are trying to clean up all local hosting of web stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can create a Rest API for that database, deploy to the company server and create a WP plugin to query this API.

I think this is the most elegant and secure way to this problem.

I have no experience with Progress OpenEdge at all, but according to their forum here is a Rest tutorial https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_development/f/19/t/12377

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a Progress developer.  The database is actually part of a proprietary financial management suite of applications.  We are able to pull data for other applications using a read-only user, but all such connections simply use an ODBC connection on the host server.  This is the first case in which I want to pull data from a host over which I have no control.